# Mongodb return all value in group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My app has following document.

```
 {
“name” : “sample1”,
“a” : 1,
“b” : 1000,
“value” : “AA”
 },
 {
 “name” : “sample2”,
 “a” : 1,
 “b” : 1000,
 “value” : “BB”
 },
 {
“name” : “sample1”,
“a” : 2,
“b” : 2000,
“value” : “CC”
 }
```

group by "a" and "b" field, then If documents have same "a" and "b" then get each data by list.
How can I return like following output list?

```
 [
 {
  “a” : 1,
  “b” : 1000,
  “result” : [
    { name : “sample1”, value : “AA” },
    { name : “sample2”, value : “BB” }
  ]
 },
 {
   “a” : 2,
   “b” : 2000,
   “result” : [
    { name : “sample1”, value : “CC” },
   ]
 }
 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with aggregation framework like this

```
 db.grp.aggregate([
   {
      $group:{
         _id:{
            a:"$a",
            b:"$b"
         },
         result:{
            $push:{
               name:"$name",
               value:"$value"
            }
         }
      }
   }
])
```

it returns

```
{
   "_id":{
      "a":2,
      "b":2000
   },
   "result":[
      {
         "name":"sample1",
         "value":"CC"
      }
   ]
}{
   "_id":{
      "a":1,
      "b":1000
   },
   "result":[
      {
         "name":"sample1",
         "value":"AA"
      },
      {
         "name":"sample2",
         "value":"BB"
      }
   ]
}
```